# Resource-id is not getting displayed in appium inspector

Tags: android-webview, appium-android, appium-inspector

Android device name: Pixel 7 [OS version: 14]
Android System WebView version: 122.0.6216.106

Resource-id and id attribute are not getting displayed in appium inspector

Steps to reproduce:

1. with android system web view 113.0.xxxx, am able to see the attribute resource-id and id
   [resource-id displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFX0u.png)
2. But from android system web view 122.0.6261.64, we are not able to see resource-id and id attribute in appium inspector
   [without resource-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0wsc.png)
3. already bug has been reported in appium [https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/19848]